# How can I draw nice boxes with rounded corners using unicode characters?

Tags: unicode

I tried using [the box drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character#Unicode) from Wikipedia, but I couldn't find vertical lines which fit the rounded corner (as you can see below, they are either off, or not connected), and the horizontal lines are too thick. Are there characters which fit these corners?

```
╭━━━━╮
│test │  
╰━━━━╯
```

Answer (score 6):

Your box consists of left and right edges (1 character width)... but you have **4 characters** along top and bottom between the edges, and **5 characters** of content (`test` and a space). You need to ensure that the same number of characters are used for alignment - don't add spaces for alignment.

Additionally, you're using U+2501 for the top / bottom, when U+2500 "*looks better*" / doesn't look too thick.

```
╭────╮
│test│  
╰────╯
╭──────╮
│ test │  
╰──────╯
```

These boxes both render fine for me in Chrome, Firefox and Edge on Windows 10.

Drawing boxes with special characters isn't really recommended for exactly these reasons - if you're rendering to a terminal, then it may work better.

---

The above text renders as shown below (on Chrome on Windows). I'm using 100% zoom in Chrome, and 100% scaling in Windows.

[image: example]

From your screenshots, it looks like you're using some scaling, however I've tried using a non-100% setting in both Chrome and Windows, but it still seems to render well for me.

It is very possible that the font is causing the issue... above is rendered using `Consolas`, but below is rendered using `Lucida Console`:

[image: example, Lucida Console]

Comment: Here's how your post looks to me in Chrome:  https://i.imgur.com/OVLH3Qj.png

Comment: Interesting, which version / OS? I've also resolved the "_thick top / bottom_", does it look better now?

Comment: Windows. Now I see you edited something. Here's how now looks, still not good:  https://i.imgur.com/WNuSux8.png   Is it possible my font is the problem? Incorrect unicode implementation?

Comment: Is your Chrome zoom / display's scaling set to something other than 100%?

Comment: I don't know right now, but I'll check. BTW, I tried it on Firefox too, and it's not good there either, so it's possible it's some system wide setting on my system.

Comment: I use consolas as my monospace font, btw.